# libtool error cd: ../..: Not a directory

Tags: bash, cd-command, libtool

Getting this very bizarre error from libtool when trying to install a package I built.  It happens when running in a subdirectory (`src/api`) of the source tree:

```
make[5]: Leaving directory '/users/galac/embray/src/slurm/src/api'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libslurm.la '/usr/local/lib'
../../libtool: line 929: cd: ../..: Not a directory
```

The relevant section of `libtool` looks like this:

```
  914 # Work around backward compatibility issue on IRIX 6.5. On IRIX 6.4+, sh
  915 # is ksh but when the shell is invoked as "sh" and the current value of
  916 # the _XPG environment variable is not equal to 1 (one), the special
  917 # positional parameter $0, within a function call, is the name of the
  918 # function.
  919 progpath=$0
  920 
  921 # The name of this program.
  922 progname=`$ECHO "$progpath" |$SED "$sed_basename"`
  923 
  924 # Make sure we have an absolute progpath for reexecution:
  925 case $progpath in
  926   [\\/]*|[A-Za-z]:\\*) ;;
  927   *[\\/]*)
  928      progdir=`$ECHO "$progpath" |$SED "$sed_dirname"`
  929      progdir=`cd "$progdir" && pwd`
  930      progpath=$progdir/$progname
  931      ;;
  932   *)
  933      _G_IFS=$IFS
  934      IFS=${PATH_SEPARATOR-:}
  935      for progdir in $PATH; do
  936        IFS=$_G_IFS
  937        test -x "$progdir/$progname" && break
  938      done
  939      IFS=$_G_IFS
  940      test -n "$progdir" || progdir=`pwd`
  941      progpath=$progdir/$progname
  942      ;;
  943 esac
```

If I insert `set -x` into the script around this section, I see the following trace:

```
+ progpath=../../libtool
++ printf '%s\n' ../../libtool
++ /bin/sed 's|^.*/||'
+ progname=libtool
+ case $progpath in
++ printf '%s\n' ../../libtool
++ /bin/sed 's|/[^/]*$||'
+ progdir=../..
++ cd ../..
../../libtool: line 930: cd: ../..: Not a directory
+ progdir=
+ progpath=/libtool
...
```

this leads to further errors since it does not set `progpath=../../libtool`, the correct path for `libtool` itself (in the top-level source dir).  It also seems to be correctly setting `progdir=../..`.  So why is `../..` not a directory?

Clearly it looks fine if I check manually:

```
~/src/slurm/src/api$ ls -ld ../..
drwxr-xr-x 11 xxxxxx xxxxx 4096 May 14 14:52 ../..
```

It is not a symlink or anything like that.

Never seen anything like this in my 20 years of development.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the `Not a directory` error. What shell outputs this message? The `bash` shell says `No such file or directory`, not just `Not a directory`.  The `dash` shell says `can't cd to <pathname>`. What system are you running on?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the comment.  That actually points me in the right direction.  I think I know what the problem is now.

Comment: BTW the shell is definitely bash, but the message is not coming from bash but rather the filesystem.  It's an nfs mount :facepalm:

Comment: @Kusalananda, you do get a `Not a directory` error in `cd /etc/passwd` or `cd /dev/null/foo`. That is, it's a `ENOTDIR` error here, not `ENOENT`. (and the message does come from `bash`'s `cd` builtin in any case based on the errno returned by `chdir(2)`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So it is, and that's true for other `cd` implementations as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that I'm on an NFS mount on an HPC system (on which I have administrative privileges).  But the error occurred when running `sudo make install`.

The NFS server appears to be using the `root_squash` option, which makes NFS mounts unreadable by the root user; see https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports

The solution is to simply move my build to a non-NFS filesystem and install from there.  Thanks to everyone who had a look.